# Convert string dd/mmm/YYYY to yyyy-mm-dd in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, date, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataset which has a date in string format that I want to convert to date in pyspark. how do I achieve this ? I tried few combinations which gives me null date though.

sample data

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 04/Oct/2022 | 5 |
| B | 10/Jan/2023 | 15 |

expected

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-10-04 | 5 |
| B | 2023-01-10 | 15 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to_date(<COL>,<date_format>)` pyspark inbuilt function for this case:

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([('A','04/Oct/2022',5),('B','10/Jan/2023',15)],['id','date','value'])
df.withColumn("date",to_date(col("date"),"dd/MMM/yyyy")).show(10,False)
#+---+----------+-----+
#|id |date      |value|
#+---+----------+-----+
#|A  |2022-10-04|5    |
#|B  |2023-01-10|15   |
#+---+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use your string parsing skills**

If I understand your question, you want to convert `04/Oct/2022` to `2022-10-04`. This should work:

```
def parse_date(date):
    months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    date = date.split("/")
    day = date[0]
    month = months.index(date[1]) + 1
    year = date[2]
    return f"{year}-{month}-{day}"

print(parse_date("04/Oct/2022"))  # 2022-10-04
```